# Screenshot of a complete building?

Tags: terraria

I saw [this](http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/76561197992627716/screenshot/560910935939130687) screenshot and I was wondering if is there a tool to take a screenshot of an entire building?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Terraria Map Generator](http://terrariamapgenerator.codeplex.com/) is an automatic option where you just crop your building from; another option is to take screenshots manually and stitching them together. You can use F11 to hide the UI, although you need to kill monsters and replace your character if you only want to see the building.

Comment: it works perfectly tnx!

Answer (score 4):

[Terrafirma](http://seancode.com/terrafirma) is a map viewer, too, but can use* textures to display the world, thus being closer to a screeshot than 1-pixel-per-tile map viewers.

*edit: you have to check “use textures” in the menu first, and be zoomed in enough to see the textures.

Comment: +1 for giving an alternative, the only difference with TMG I see is the background which could also be changed with an external editor. But perhaps it might work better, I haven't used both so I can't tell...

Comment: check “use textures” in the menu and zoom in.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it from the screenshots. That option doesn't seem to work for me...

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the game is just set to a very high resolution.

You can press F11 to remove the HUD.

Comment: You can also take several screenshots without a hud and then edit them together with a panorama-software or manually in an image editing application.

Comment: Thats true.  I just meant this specific one looks that way because there is only one PC in the very center.

Comment: True. (With enough shots for panorama you can remove your avatar completely, or wherever you want.)